# limit characters in dynamic text box in data list asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, javascript, asp-classic

In the JavaScript below I have a problem in that the JavaScript applies only to one text box not to all the text area's because the ID generated in the html is different for all text area's. Any help regarding to this

```
   <font>Maximum Number of characters for this text box is 255.<br>
                                <textarea runat="server" id="txtAnswerMain" onkeypress="return taLimit(this)" onkeyup="return taCount(this,'myCounter')"
                                    name="Description" rows="7" wrap="physical" cols="40">
                                </textarea>
```

this is the java script i am using it works for single text area but when i apply to dynamically created text area it does not work

```
  <script language="Javascript">
        maxL = 100;
        var bName = navigator.appName;
        function taLimit(taObj) {
            if (taObj.value.length == maxL) return false;
            return true;
        }

        function taCount(taObj, Cnt) {
            objCnt = createObject(Cnt);
            objVal = taObj.value;
            if (objVal.length > maxL) objVal = objVal.substring(0, maxL);
            if (objCnt) {
                if (bName == "Netscape") {
                    objCnt.textContent = maxL - objVal.length;
                }
                else { objCnt.innerText = maxL - objVal.length; }
            }
            return true;
        }
        function createObject(objId) {
            if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
            else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
            else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
            else return eval("document." + objId);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I dynamically add a textarea using JQuery it works fine.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divToAddTo').append('<textarea id="txtAnswerMain2" onkeypress="return taLimit(this)" onkeyup="return taCount(this,'myCounter')" name="Description" rows="7" wrap="physical" cols="40">');
$('#divToAddTo').append('</textarea>');
});
</script>
```